# Fourier transform of f(x)/x

Tags: fourier-transform

***Is there a relation to the Fourier transform of the following statement?***
$$\tau(\frac{f(x)}{x})=??$$  and $$\tau(\frac{f(x)}{x^{2}})=??$$
Is this correct?
$$\tau(\frac{f(x)}{x})=\tau(f(x))\tau(\frac{1}{x})$$
I want to know if there is a relationship like this?
$$\tau(x^{n} f(x))=(-i)^{n}\frac{d^{n}}{dk^{n}}F(k)$$

Comment: There's more than one way to transform $xf(x)/x$

Comment: The Fourier transform of a product is not the product of the transforms. Instead it's the convolution of the transforms (perhaps times a factor, depending of what definition of the transform is used).

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal F_{x\to\xi}\{f(x)\} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, e^{-i\xi x} \, dx.$ Then we have $\mathcal F_{x\to\xi}\{x \, f(x)\} = i \frac{d}{d\xi} \mathcal F_{x\to\xi}\{f(x)\}.$ This implies that
$$\mathcal F_{x\to\xi}\{f(x)\} = \mathcal F_{x\to\xi}\left\{ x \, \frac{f(x)}{x} \right\} = i \frac{d}{d\xi} \mathcal F_{x\to\xi}\left\{ \frac{f(x)}{x} \right\}$$

Therefore
$$ \mathcal F_{x\to\xi}\left\{ \frac{f(x)}{x} \right\} = -i \int \mathcal F_{x\to\xi}\{f(x)\} \, d\xi + C.$$

Comment: what is Fourier transform of  $$\delta(x)f(x)&&?

Comment: Since $\delta(x) \, f(x) = f(0) \, \delta(x)$ and $\mathcal F_{x\to\xi}\{\delta(x)\} = 1$ we get $\mathcal F_{x\to\xi}\{f(x) \, \delta(x) \} = f(0).$

Comment: thank you. what is inverse Laplace of $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{Γ(b+as^{\alpha})}{Γ(b+as^{\alpha}-n)}$$??

Comment: I'm sorry, but that one is too complicated for me.

Comment: is Fourier transform of  $$\delta(x)f(x)&& true??Why did not you use convolution theory?

Comment: $$\tau(\delta(x)f(x))=\tau(f(0)\delta(x))=??$$
How to use convolution theorem to solve it?

Comment: $$\mathcal F_{x\to\xi}\{f(x) \, \delta(x) \} = \int f(x) \, \delta(x) \, e^{-i\xi x} \, dx = f(0) \, e^{-i\xi \cdot 0} = f(0)$$

Comment: Using convolution theorem:
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal F_{x\to\xi}\{f(x) \, \delta(x) \} 
& = \frac{1}{2\pi} \mathcal F_{x\to\xi}\{f(x)\} * \mathcal F_{x\to\xi}\{\delta(x)\} \\
& = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int \mathcal F_{x\to\xi'}\{f(x)\} \, \mathbf 1(\xi-\xi') \, d\xi' \\
& = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int \mathcal F_{x\to\xi'}\{f(x)\} \, d\xi' \\
& = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int \left( \int f(x) \, e^{-i\xi' x} \, dx \right) \, d\xi' \\
& = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int f(x) \, \left( \int e^{-i\xi' x} \, d\xi' \right) \, dx \\
& = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int f(x) \, 2\pi \, \delta(x) \, dx \\
& = f(0)
\end{align}$$